# Parse CSV From HTML form and Insert into MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, html, csv

I'm trying to take an array and insert it into seperate rows in a MYSQL database.

Basically, there's an HTML form for a top 5 list that I want to input in one field, but with each value seperated by commas. So, for example (Artist 1, Artist 2, Artist 3, etc.)

These 5 values then have to be seperated into 5 values that are then inserted into 5 rows in a MYSQL database.

So the HTML form looks like this:

```
 <tr>
 <td>Loud Rock</td>
 <td><label for="lr_topfive"><input type="text" placeholder="" name="lr_topfive" size="75"
 maxlength="100" autofucus required /></label></td>
 </tr>
```

and the form value is sent to another php file with this code in it:

```
$val = $_POST['lr_topfive'];
$data = str_getcsv($val);

??????


$lr_one = mysql_prep($_POST['lr_one']);
$lr_two = mysql_prep($_POST['lr_two']);
$lr_three = mysql_prep($_POST['lr_three']);
$lr_four = mysql_prep($_POST['lr_four']);
$lr_five = mysql_prep($_POST['lr_five']);

$query = "INSERT INTO xyz_wb (lr_one, lr_two, lr_three, lr_four, lr_five) VALUES ('{$lr_one}','{$lr_two}', '{$lr_three}', '{$lr_four}', '{$lr_five}')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if ($result) {
        redirect_to("email-ready.php");
    } else {
    //display error message
    echo "<p>Yikes!</p>";
    echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
    }
```

I get that the 'lr_topfive' value is parsed and seperated into distinct values by the first two lines, but I dont know what to do before inserting these values into the MYSQL DB.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/)

Comment: http://pradipchitrakar.com.np/programming/upload-csv-mysql-php/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just looking for:

```
$top_five_array = explode(',', $_POST['lr_topfive']);
```

and then:

```
$lr_one = mysql_prep($top_five_array[0]);
$lr_two = mysql_prep($top_five_array[1]);
....
```

However, this will break if there are not exactly 4 comma's in your input field.

Apart from that you need to switch to prepared statements using PDO or mysqli, see the comments below your question.

Comment: How would I insert the ($top_five_array[0]) variables into the DB? Wouldn't I need to turn it back into a string first?

Comment: @user1478878 That's what I was doing in the second part, assigning it to `$lr_one`, etc.